# How to call a function at regular interval which accesses and updates UI controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, gridview

The basic Idea of this web app is a chatroom and the `GridView` showing the chats should be refreshed by selecting latest chats from database and storing in `DataTable` which is the `DataSource` of the `Gridview`. The `GridView`'s markup is as follows:-

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Width="545px" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" HeaderStyle-Height="0px">
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderStyle Height="0px" Wrap="False" />
                <ItemStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" Width="394px" 
                    BorderStyle="None" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("user") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text=": "></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("chat") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("date") %>' Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Gray"></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle BorderStyle="None" Height="0px" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

There's of course another `GridView` containing users names. When one of them is clicked the `RowCommand` event is fired:-

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    int rowValue = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    GridView1.SelectedIndex = rowValue;
    show_chats();

}
```

And Finally, here's the `show_chats` function:-

```
    public void show_chats()
{
        if (GridView1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            LinkButton ul = (LinkButton)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("userList");
            string gridViewValue = ul.Text;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from chats where (chatFrom='" + user + "' and chatTo='" + gridViewValue + "') OR (chatFrom='" + gridViewValue + "' and chatTo='" + user + "')  order by dateTime", conn);
            conn.Close();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                txtChat.Text = "No past chats, Type here to get started";
                chats.Clear();
                GridView2.DataSource = chats;
                GridView2.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                chats.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow row = chats.NewRow();
                    row[0] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                    row[1] = dt.Rows[i][2].ToString();
                    row[2] = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                    chats.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                GridView2.DataSource = chats;
                GridView2.DataBind();
                txtChat.Text = "";
            }

        }

}
```

Now I want the `show_chats` function to be called at regular interval to check for new messages whenever an user is selected from `GridView1` (which contains the user names).

I tried using thread but I guess I'm doing it wrong, because it is throwing exceptions which are not thrown when I am not using thread.
If I have to use threading please tell me how to use it properly.

Comment: This has actually nothing to do with c# nor does it have anything to do with multithreading. use Ajax.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with ajax, but I guess I'll give it a try

Comment: Ajax is the way to go if you want to refresh a part of your page every X time. if you want to refresh the hole page a simple javascript using `SetTimeout` will do the the trick.

Comment: The request always comes from the client-side. So indeed, the easiest way to handle this is to do the periodic refresh from the client side - `setTimeout` is just fine. If you want to experiment a bit more with some more modern technologies, SignalR could also work pretty well - and it would infact allow you to hook it up to `SqlDependency` monitoring the chatroom - so you'll only have to refresh when there's an actual change.

Comment: +1 to Luaan for suggesting SignalR. I totally forgot about this option. It's been a long time since I've worked on web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'Threading.Thread' for independent execution of a function and Threading.Timer to call that function on interval.

Declaring Threading.Timer :

```
System.Threading.Timer TimerForXYZ = new System.Threading.Timer(TickForXYZ, null, 0, 1000); // this will call method TickForXYZ after every 1 second
```

Declaring Threading.Thread :

```
    private void TickForXYZ(object obj)
    {
        Thread myThreadXYZ = new Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(XYZ));
        myThreadXYZ .IsBackground = true;
        myThreadXYZ .Start();
    }
```

Your Method to run periodically :

```
private void XYZ()
{
    // Your code goes here
    // This function will run after every 1s
}
```

Alternately you can use timers in javascript to call a ajax function, which will load your grid.

Let me know if you need any help with this.

Comment: Pravin, this code is behaving oddly. The first time it ran alright, but when I ran it again, it seemed the function XYZ wasn't fired. It went like that for a few times. Then I cleared cookies of the browser and logged in the application and it worked allright. But then again, I re-ran the app and it didn't work.

Comment: I want to go with javaScript/Ajax, if you can help me, it would be great. I am completely unaware of AjAx